# How can I easily customize Apache web server error pages

Tags: apache-2.2

How can I easily customize Apache web server error pages.

I found some localization strings which look like nightmare. I just want to set a nice "server busy" page in one locale whenever mod_proxy cannot connect to sub-server.

What is the easiest way? Copy file where? It's filename is what? Do I need to tweak a config setting?

I am looking for a copy-paste solution instead of documentation.... Now I am getting

```
"Service Temporarily Unavailable"
```

page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize error page with the [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive, the code you want to customize are probably 504 and 502, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html for a full list of possible code.

Comment: Any example code? I am looking for a copy-paste solution instead of documentation.... Now I am getting "Service Temporarily Unavailable" page. Not sure what error code.. not found? Anyways, I can tweak the code later.

Comment: "Service Temporarily Unavailable" is code 503. There is already 4 example in the link of the documentation, just change the code by 503 and the link to the html page you want to diplay

Comment: You mean ErrorDocument 503 http://foo.example.com/myerrorpage

Ok, thanx. I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

you can change on following locations

`#/var/www/error/`

Comment: What is this? Config option or location or...? I apologise for being bit new to this.

Comment: HI MARTIN, not worry boss!! on that location you'll have all error file just edit as you needed, i have done same fun out there for my server's

Comment: I don't have such directory as /var/www/error/. Is it a symbolic link?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Plesk, your error documents are stored in:

> /var/www/vhosts/*yourdomain*/error_docs/

If you want to change the error documents for all domains you create, the templates are stored in:

> /var/www/vhosts/.skel/0/error_docs/

But modifying the documents in this latter directory will only affect new domains, not existing ones, which you will have to either manually modify their "error_docs" files in, or use some script to replace all of the documents in all directories.